# C changing variable is being stepped over

Tags: c, msp430

My issue arises with the variable `total`. The debugger steps over like it's not even there, or if you get rid of the `*`, it runs and runs and provides a weird number. The idea of the program is to add dimes (or 10) to the `total` until it is greater than the goal which is `10000`.

I'm writing this in C with IAR Embedded Workbench and am using a MSP430G2553.

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>
#include <stdio.h>
volatile unsigned int i;
int dime=0;
int goalz =10000;
int main( void )
{
      // Stop watchdog timer to prevent time out reset
      WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;
      P1DIR |= 0x00;
      for(;;){
        P1OUT =0x01;
        while(1)
        {
          if((BIT4 & P1IN)) 
          {
            P1OUT |= 0x01;
            dime++;
            int *total = 0;
            *total = &dime;
          }
          else
          {
            P1OUT |= 0x00;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `P1OUT |= 0x00;` is a no-op.  Did you have in mind `P1OUT &= ~0x01;` to reset the least significant bit?  The compiler should have warned about a type mismatch in the assignment `*total = &dime;` — heed your compiler's warnings.  If it warns, it is because your code is so wrong that it thinks it can't just compile it without letting you know you've probably made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

```
int *total = 0;
*total = &dime;
```

that is *wrong*, because you're trying to store the address of `dime` (not its value) in the location pointed by `total`, i.e. zero => not what you want (someone suggests this is the location of a register, so even if it doesn't crash, it's not valid. Writing the INTENA register is *not* good!).

The debugger probably optimizes out this statement, writing directly in zero.

not completely sure of what you want to achieve, but you have to declare `total` as a global variable and add `dime` to it. No need to use pointers or variable addresses here.

Comment: On the MSP430x2xx, address 0 contains the interrupt enable register.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the debugger is steps over since the compiler is not even generating the code. You are creating the variable total (pointer or integer) in the stack (i.e., you add an item), you assign a value, and then you are out of scope so the variable is not there anymore.

I think that what you are trying to achieve is:

```
if (...) {
  static int total = 0;
  total = dime
}
```

but, then again, the variable total is completely useless, since it will always be the same value as dime. How should be `total` and `dime` different?